# How to access the details (i.e sub fields) of second/third elements that has the same class name in selenium using python?

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver, screen-scraping

I have 3 elements with a particular instance (eg.: there are 3 `<div class="sc-1xo2hia-0 TegxE">` under each `<div direction="vertical" class="sc-1fp9csv-0 iFnncD">` in the webiste: https://www.blockchain.com/btc/block/00000000000000000004b91bad9ecfa8c0e57c256d0007cca6f0a2a9e54a2ccc ; click 'Inspect element' on the first transaction to view the specific DOM tree)

Now I want to access the some elements from 2nd and 3rd instance of the first tag (`sc-1xo2hia-0 TegxE`)

How do I do this efficiently?

PS: This code :

`from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.blockchain.com/btc/block/00000000000000000004b91bad9ecfa8c0e57c256d0007cca6f0a2a9e54a2ccc')
Txn_elements=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="sc-1fp9csv-0 iFnncD"]')
length=len(Txn_elements)
for i in range(0,length):
    element=Txn_elements[i]
    data=element.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='sc-1xo2hia-0 TegxE'][1]")
    print data[0].text`

still prints details of the 0th `<div class="sc-1xo2hia-0 TegxE">` only 
i.e. it still prints:

`Hash 
fc1630ec40d95da3fcca40d499c4be616ea6591dda6f0d3d85a678d47c91ae62
2019-11-06 8:37 PM`

where as it should have printed:

`17A16QmavnUfCW11DAApiJxp7ARnxN5pGX
2.62352930 BTC`

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
xpath= (.//div[@class='ge5wha-0 bLrlXr']/a)[1] //to get 17A16QmavnUfCW11DAApiJxp7ARnxN5pGX
xpath = (.//div[@class='ge5wha-1 bWdiuU']/span)[1] //to get 2.62352930 BTC
```

try with this `xpath`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below solution its working but I am not sure why you are using for loop if you just want to print two elements in the `//div[@class="sc-1fp9csv-0 iFnncD"]`

if you want to print only one then remove for loop and try to execute your code

```
driver.get('https://www.blockchain.com/btc/block/00000000000000000004b91bad9ecfa8c0e57c256d0007cca6f0a2a9e54a2ccc')
Txn_elements=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="sc-1fp9csv-0 iFnncD"]')
length=len(Txn_elements)
for i in range(0,length):
    element=Txn_elements[i]
    data=element.find_elements_by_xpath("//body/div[@id='__next']/div[@class='sc-1myx216-0 iygrgv']/div[@class='p5q4id-0 fasJHc sc-5vnaz6-1 doVOgS']/div[@class='fieq4h-0 klQmUt']/div[@class='xoxfsb-0 bmukdK']/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]")
    print data[0].text

    data1 = element.find_elements_by_xpath(
        " //body/div[@id='__next']/div[@class='sc-1myx216-0 iygrgv']/div[@class='p5q4id-0 fasJHc sc-5vnaz6-1 doVOgS']/div[@class='fieq4h-0 klQmUt']/div[@class='xoxfsb-0 bmukdK']/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span")
    print data1[0].text
```

Try below the solution for transaction ID

```
driver.get('https://www.blockchain.com/btc/block/00000000000000000004b91bad9ecfa8c0e57c256d0007cca6f0a2a9e54a2ccc')


List1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//body/div[@id='__next']/div[@class='sc-1myx216-0 iygrgv']/div[@class='p5q4id-0 fasJHc sc-5vnaz6-1 doVOgS']/div[@class='fieq4h-0 klQmUt']/div[@class='xoxfsb-0 bmukdK']/div[*]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/a")
for items in List1:
    print (items.text)

List2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//body/div[@id='__next']/div[@class='sc-1myx216-0 iygrgv']/div[@class='p5q4id-0 fasJHc sc-5vnaz6-1 doVOgS']/div[@class='fieq4h-0 klQmUt']/div[@class='xoxfsb-0 bmukdK']/div[*]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/span")
for items in List2:
    print (items.text)
```

Comment: Actually I want to print all transaction details from a page, so I need a loop structure. I mostly want a way to access later elements while using find_elements method.
See the indexing that I have done in my code..the 2nd last line.
Its not working as it is supposed to.
Can you help with that?

Comment: Try the above solution